# How to fix rendering page error in express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

My app is a simple blog that displays a schema of the blog title, entry, date, and then a edit/delete page that isn't complete yet.  The edit/delete will be for the post that was selected and it takes you to the .../blogList/blogEdit/_id page.  When I click on the edit/delete button on the blog post it gives me a 404 error.

app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var debug = require('debug')('app');
require('./app_server/models/db');

const todoRouter = require('./app_server/routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app_server', 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

...

app.get('/', todoRouter);
app.get('/blogAdd', todoRouter);
app.get('/blogList', todoRouter);
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ctrlHome = require('../controllers/home');
var ctrlBlogA = require('../controllers/blog');
var ctrlBlogL = require('../controllers/blogL');

router.get('/', ctrlHome.bHome);
router.get('/blogAdd', ctrlBlogA.bAdd);
router.get('/blogList', ctrlBlogL.bList);
router.get('/blogList/blogEdit/:id', ctrlBlogL.eList);
router.get('/blogList/blogDelete/:id', ctrlBlogL.dList);

module.exports = router;
```

controller/blogL.js

```
module.exports.bList = function(req, res){
        res.render('blogList', {
                title: 'Blog List',
                pageHeader: {
                        title: 'Blog List',
                },
                blog: [{
                                blogTitle: 'We did one!',
                                blogEntry: 'I hope this gets put into my blog',
                                blogDate: '9/22/2020'
                },{
                                blogTitle: 'We did two!',
                                blogEntry: 'I did it',
                                blogDate: '9/24/2020'
                },{
                                blogTitle: 'Third entry',
                                blogEntry: 'complete',
                                blogDate: '9/24/2020'
                }]
        });
};

module.exports.eList = function(req, res){
                res.render('blogEdit', {title: 'Blog Edit'});
};
module.exports.dList = function(req, res){
                res.render('blogDelete', { title: 'Blog Delete' });
};
```

blogList.jade - portion that is supposed to render all the schemas

```
      p
      each blogs in blog
       .col-xs-12.list-group-item
        h4
         p
          h4= blogs.blogTitle
         p
          h4= blogs.blogEntry
         p
          h4= blogs.blogDate
          //error is here I assume
          a.btn.btn-default.pull-right(href="/blogEdit") Edit
          a.btn.btn-default.pull-right(href="/blogDelete") Delete
```

Comment: You have `href="/blogEdit"` but route is `/blogList/blogEdit/:id'`

Comment: Yes, correctly said.

Comment: When I add /blogList/blogEdit/:id it still won't render the blogEdit or blogDelete page

Answer (score 0):

In app.js there needs to be app.get('...') that has the /blogList/.../_id in it, to allow the app to use the pages.